# Default format when casting date(time) to varchar

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime, sql-server-2014

What is the default format that is used when I cast date or datetime into varchar? What settings affect the result? Did I come to the right conclusion that date always converts into `YYYY-MM-DD` and `datetime` is only affected by `language`?

```
declare @myDatetime as datetime = dateadd(day,3,getutcdate());
declare @myDate     as date     = @myDatetime;

set dateformat  ymd;        --no difference?
set language    us_english; --affects datetime only?

select
    cast(@myDate     as varchar(max))   --2017-10-13
,   cast(@myDatetime as varchar(max))   --Oct 13 2017  1:47PM
;

set dateformat  dmy;        --no difference?

select
    cast(@myDate     as varchar(max))   --2017-10-13
,   cast(@myDatetime as varchar(max))   --Oct 13 2017  1:47PM
;

set language    Lithuanian; --affects datetime only?

select
    cast(@myDate     as varchar(max))   --2017-10-13
,   cast(@myDatetime as varchar(max))   --spl 13 2017  1:56PM
;
```

Comment: as far as I know, date and datetime are both dependent on your serverside settings and/or language settings. Anyways, I prefer to provide a defined format when converting date or datetime to string and back again - gives you a bit more control on what your query actually does.

Comment: http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp#DtFormatsInput

Comment: I prefer to not get date(time) values in queries as strings in the first place. It is almost always better to return a datetime datatype and let the front end deal with presentation.

Comment: Actually we have a table with some date columns. The source data type is just varchar. Sometimes the ETL fails because of the conversion. We'll probably just change the date columns into varchar, to prevent the ETL from failing and try_cast() them into a date on the next layer. So the simplest way to change the data type seems to be `alter table x alter column y varchar(10) null;`, cause it's simple and retains the column order.

Comment: PSA: [ISO date format](https://xkcd.com/1179/).

Comment: Changing date columns into varchar columns is something you should never do. Better check the conversion procedure and improve it

Comment: @SeanLange - but when you are building a string from datetime values - for example, to prepare a SQL statement, it becomes essential to predict how your script will format those values.